# Laravel multiple delete checkbox

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Hi gladly I want to delete only checked tasks. So to achieve that I use an array variable for the name attribute for my checkbox.

At the moment I have this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle selDelete" data-toggle="dropdown" id="deleteTask">
        <input id="check1" name="deleteCheckedTask[]" type="checkbox" class="check" value="{{$Task->id}}">
        <span class="caret-hover caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selDelete" role="menu">
        <li><a class="deleteTask" href= "{{ route('user.tasks.destroy',array( $Task->id )) }}" data-method="delete" >Deletey</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Which looks like this in the browser:
link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaAsC.png

But this wil only send the id of 1 task that's going to be deleted.

I have also tried this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle selDelete" data-toggle="dropdown" id="deleteTask">
        <input id="check1" name="deleteCheckedTask[]" type="checkbox" class="check" value="{{$Task->id}}">
        <span class="caret-hover caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selDelete" role="menu">
        <li><a class="deleteTask" href= "{{ route('user.tasks.destroy',array( $deleteCheckedTask)) }}" data-method="delete" >Deletey</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

But then I get the error undefined variable, here is a screenshot of the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyz9u.png

And this is how my delete() from TasksController.php currently looks like:

```
public function destroy($id){
    //$deleteCheckedTasks=array();
    $deleteCheckedTasks=Input::get('deleteCheckedTask');
    //die(print_r(Input::get('deleteCheckedTask')));
    foreach ($deleteCheckedTasks as $key => $value ) {
        print 'val: '. $key ;
    }


    //$row= DB::table('ordertasks')->where('id', $id)->first();
    //Task::destroy($id);
    //Task::destroy($row->id_task);
    //Ordertask::destroy($id);
    //delete werkt niet op vu nam zijn pc
    if (Request::path()=='api/v1/tasks/'.$id) {
        return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'tasks' => 'task deleted'),
        200
    );

    }

    return Redirect::route('user.tasks.index');
}
```

I know how I can do this with jQuery, but I gladly want to do this with Laravel. Can someone help me, please? I think that I'm very close.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it in a form

### html with blade syntax

```
<form method="POST" action="/destroy">
    {{ Form::token() }}
    @foreach($tasks as $t)
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="{{ $t->id }}">
            {{ $t->name }}
        </label>
    @endforeach
    <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

### route

```
Route::post('/destroy', array('before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'TaskController@handleDestroy'));
```

### TaskController.php

```
<?php

    class TaskController extends BaseController {
        public function handleDestroy() {
            $checked = Input::only('checked')['checked'];
            // Do whatever you want with this array
        }
    }
```